# Using Syn library to simulate drag and drop on Qunit/PhantomJS

Tags: phantomjs, qunit, automated-tests, teaspoon

I keep getting this same error ->  Argument 1 of Document.elementFromPoint is not a finite floating-point value.

I am trying to drag the 'group' element to the addGroupBtn. However I can't seem to get any simulation to work, I even ran in teaspoon browser and still obtain the same error. I tested in console but couldn't achieve the results. Maybe its just a syntax error or misunderstanding of documents on my part. Also the framework is ruby on rails using ember.js

Here is the documentation to this library: http://v3.javascriptmvc.com/docs.html#&who=Syn.drag

```
group = $("#group-0-header").children("i")
addGroupBtn = $("#add-group")
Syn.click({}, group).drag(group, addGroupBtn, {})
```

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: @lft93ryt Unfortunately I did not. We bailed on the test and left it for manual QA at the time. Wish you the best of luck.